# Create a Javascript matrix calculator with 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, matrix, calculator

I have a form with two input fields:

```
<form>
 <select name="width">
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="...">...</option>
   <option value="300">300</option>
 </select>
 <select name="height">
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="...">...</option>
   <option value="300">300</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

How can I "calculate" the number of items that we need to use for tiling. See screenshot.
Example, if you select width = 60 and height = 60 than the result will be 12.
The result is always the end of the row and column where the two values cross eachother.

[image]

My guess is that I can do it with a 2d array? But I'm not sure if this is possible because what if the width and height are both 15.

Comment: What is the math behind the resulting number? How does 15 and 15 come down to 89?

Comment: _"because what if the width and height are both 15."_ - what then? Then you access the first array dimension using that first 15, and the second array dimension using that second 15. What makes you think this was _any_ different from accessing the value for 90-30 or 150-25, _at all_ ...?

Comment: @0stone0 those will be _given_ values here, that the 2d array provides.

Comment: This problem is that there is no formula to go from 15 and 15 to 89. We just need to follow the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea what the formula should be, I feel like the *correct* solution would be to work out the value based on the two inputs:

```js
function calculate(widthValue, heightValue) {
    // perform magic
}

calculate(15, 15); // -> 89
```

The only thing that I can think so do would be to have some nested objects with the values contained within it.

```js
const results = {
    15: {
        15: 89
    },
    20: {
        15: 67,
        20: 50
    },
    // ...
};

const width = document.querySelector("select[name=\"width\"]");
const height = document.querySelector("select[name=\"height\"]");

function getValue() {

    const values = results[width.value];

    if (!values) {
        console.warn("Unable to find a value for %o", width.value);
        return;
    }

    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(values, height.value)) {
        return values[height.value];
    }
    
    console.warn("There is no value for %o x %o", width.value, height.value);

}

width.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const value = getValue();
    if (value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
});
height.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const value = getValue();
    if (value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

```html
 <select name="width">
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="...">...</option>
   <option value="300">300</option>
 </select>
 <select name="height">
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="...">...</option>
   <option value="300">300</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: The problem is that there is not formula. We just need to follow the table.

Comment: @Dennis then the code that I've given you will do it, if you fill in the rest of the results

Comment: Thank you for this @James Long.
How can you fix the issue if the height value is greater than the width value. I would guess that you switch the values?

Comment: @Dennis yeah, you can do that pretty easily in JavaScript these days. `let widthValue = width.value; let heightValue = height.value; if (heightValue > widthValue) { [widthValue, heightValue] = [heightValue, widthValue]; }`

Comment: Thanks for your quick responsive. I've added the code in the getValue() function. It seems to work but for most of the values not. I've added the full code to a codepen: https://codepen.io/dennisperremans/pen/bGxqNVX If you select width = 50 and height = 150, nothing will happen. But If you select width = 30 and height =  90 , it works.

Comment: It seems to act strange if the height or width is >= 100

Comment: @Dennis maybe a better approach would be to populate the dropdowns with the available values. https://codepen.io/James-Long-the-typescripter/pen/KKxWpeR

Comment: @Jason, I don't the the issue with how the dropdowns are populated right now. The values in the dropdown are correct and correspond with the values in the matrix variable.

Comment: Also your example doesn't seem to work when you first set the height and then the width. Example: height = 15 and width = 20

Comment: @Dennis I threw it together quickly to show the idea. I've updated the pen to show what I mean: the dropdowns are only populated with the available values so you can't select an option that doesn't have a value and you can't set the height first.